# how does this phrase translate this way?

Tags: translation

"Hyakuman kai no "Aishiteru" nanka yori mo

Zutto zutto taisetsu ni suru mono ga aru"

is translated as

"There’s something much, much more important
Than the millionth “I love you”"

I'm not even close to put this phrase together.
Aru is "there are"
suru mono I suppose is something like "things to do" 
zutto zutto = ? always ?
taitetsu = important

I guess that can be something like "There are things to do always more important.." (probably I misstranslated a lot) . What's indicating the "ni" in this line and after "important" ?

Now the first phrase is much more difficult:

Hyakuman kai no "Aishiteru" nanka yori mo

Hyakuman = a million, a lot
kai = ? no idea what it is here, kai is used for many kanjis and I dont know what it is here . Does hyakuman kai altogether means a million times?
"aishiteru" = I love you . "hyakuman kai no "aishiteru" perhaps means something like "a million times of I love you" ?

nanka = something

yorimo = than

I can't put this line together. Specially what does the nanka is doing here? What's the most literal translation for the whole 2 lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The translation you provided is not a literal one, but I think it's correct. A more literal one could go like this:

> [百万]{hyakuman}[回]{kai}[の]{no}「[愛してる]{aishiteru}」[なんか]{nanka}[より]{yori}[も]{mo}
>   *Rather than a million "I love you",*

- [百万]{hyakuman}[回]{kai}[の]{no}「[愛してる]{aishiteru}」: A million times "I love you"
- [なんか]{nanka}: things like (this word means that the singer doesn't appreciate the meaningless "I love you"'s and wants something else)
- [より]{yori}[も]{mo}: rather than

> [ずっと]{zutto}[ずっと]{zutto}[大切]{taisetsu}[に]{ni}[する]{suru}[もの]{mono}[が]{ga}[ある]{aru}
>   *there are things I treasure much, much more*

- [大切]{taisetsu}[に]{ni}[する]{suru}: a verb expression meaning "to treasure" in *attributive form* (modifying the following noun, [もの]{mono})
- [もの]{mono}[が]{ga}[ある]{aru}: there are things

Comment: 大切にする doesn't translate into an adjective. It simply means "(which) I cherish" or "I treasure" etc.

Comment: @broccoliforest Thanks. Is the information about attributive form still correct?

Comment: Do you mean the part you wrote about the attributive form? Yes, and it is attributive form.